# scala - serialize Int to ArrayBuffer[Byte]. Bit twiddle goes wrong

Tags: scala, bit-manipulation

I want to serialize an into into a Byte array or array buffer.

I realise that I can use 'java.nio.ByteBuffer' but I am experimenting for fun and trying to do it myself.

The following code works for positive Int but goes wrong when I serialize a negative Int.
Can anyone explain why or show me a correction?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object b {
  val INTBYTES:Int = 4 // int is 4 bytes

  def toArrayBuf(x:Int): ArrayBuffer[Byte] = {
    val buf = new ArrayBuffer[Byte](INTBYTES)
    for(i <- 0 until INTBYTES) {
      buf += ((x >>> (INTBYTES - i - 1 << 3)) & 0xFF).toByte
    }
    buf
  }
}
```

the following test works as expected:-
int the REPL it prints:-

```
scala> val test:Int = 0x4f0f0f0f
test: Int = 1326386959

scala> println(test.toBinaryString)
1001111000011110000111100001111

scala> val t1 = b.toArrayBuf(test)
t1: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Byte] = ArrayBuffer(79, 15, 15, 15)

scala> t1.foreach( it => printf("%s ",it.toInt.toBinaryString))
1001111 1111 1111 1111
```

but this with a negative int does something wierd:-

```
scala> val test2:Int = 0x8f0f0f0f
test2: Int = -1894838513

scala> println(test2.toBinaryString)
10001111000011110000111100001111

scala> val t2 = b.toArrayBuf(test2)
t2: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Byte] = ArrayBuffer(-113, 15, 15, 15)

scala> t2.foreach( it => printf("%s ",it.toInt.toBinaryString))
11111111111111111111111110001111 1111 1111 1111
```

notice that the first byte has been 1 filled for the whole int it shoild be '10001111'

Any ideas?

FYI 
Im using :-

```
scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.1 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
java -fullversion
java full version "1.7.0_40-b31"
with OpenJDK
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to things like this in scala, you might want to take a look at akka.util.ByteString and its builder. It contains all kinds of useful methods to convert primitives with different endianness. And it is immutable, so it is not quite as lowlevel as ByteBuffer.
http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/index.html#akka.util.ByteStringBuilder

Comment: Good advice Rudiger, I would use that, but as I mentioned I was experimenting for myself to get a better understanding, Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking Luigi's advice I hacked up a pimp for Byte that provides a toBinaryString that works properly, in case anyone else is struggling with similar problems here is what I did.

```
object b {
  val INTBYTES:Int = 4 // int is 4 bytes
  val SIZEBYTE:Short = 8

  def toArrayBuf(x:Int): ArrayBuffer[Byte] = {
    val buf = new ArrayBuffer[Byte](INTBYTES)
    for(i <- 0 until INTBYTES) {
      buf += ((x >>> (INTBYTES - i - 1 << 3)) & 0xFF).toByte
    }
    buf
  }

  def toBinaryString(x: Byte): String = {
    val buf = new StringBuilder(SIZEBYTE)
    for(i <- 0 until SIZEBYTE) {
      buf.append((x >>> (SIZEBYTE - i - 1)) & 0x01)
    }
    buf.toString()
  }
}

//pimp Byte
implicit def fooBar(byte: Byte) = new {def toBinaryString = b.toBinaryString(byte)}
```

Now when I run the previous experiment it works properly

```
scala> val test:Int = 0x4f0f0f0f
test: Int = 1326386959

scala> println(test.toBinaryString)
1001111000011110000111100001111

scala> val t1 = toArrayBuf(test)
t1: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Byte] = ArrayBuffer(79, 15, 15, 15)

scala> t1.foreach( it => printf("%s ",it.toBinaryString))
01001111 00001111 00001111 00001111
```

and

```
scala> val test2:Int = 0x8f0f0f0f
test2: Int = -1894838513

scala> println(test2.toBinaryString)
10001111000011110000111100001111

scala> val t2 = toArrayBuf(test2)
t2: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Byte] = ArrayBuffer(-113, 15, 15, 15)

scala> t2.foreach( it => printf("%s ",it.toBinaryString))
10001111 00001111 00001111 00001111
```

Thanks Luigi

Answer (score 3):

Scala's `toBinaryString` method defers to the Java one on `Integer`. From those documents:

> public static String toBinaryString(int i)
>
> Returns a string representation of the integer argument as an unsigned
>   integer in base 2.  The unsigned integer value is the argument plus
>   2^32 if the argument is negative; otherwise it is equal to the
>   argument. This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in
>   binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0s.

In other words it's working as specified. Your bit-twiddling seems to be OK, but when you're printing the numbers out, you need to realise that the number of characters is dependent on the length of the data type. (E.g. -1: Int in binary is 11111111111111111111111111111111 while -1: Byte is 11111111.) You get away with it for positive numbers only because the leading zeros are not displayed, as specified above.

Solution: make your own `toBinaryString` for bytes, or just taking the rightmost 8 digits from the Int version should work (though less efficient) i.e.

```
it.toInt.toBinaryString.takeRight(8)
```

Comment: Great! thanks for the answer. I'm glad the bit twiddle was correct, seems a shame that scala doesn't have helpful binary presentation formats and convertions for the close to the machine types.